# How to show additional images in Xcode layout in landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I created Size Classes for both Portrait and Landscape orientation.  When I run the app, the additional images that I configured in Landscape orientation does not show.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: you need to check for constraints the four images that are displayed must be equal width and equal height and the two images near the soundtrack image [Upper image must have leading - 0 trailing  - 0 and bottom - 0] and  [the below image must have leading - 0 bottom - 0 and top 0 although contraints to be 0000 ] should I show you a demo ?

Comment: So, I should explicitly set the width and height of all of the images?  All if the images are in stack views, surrounded by an encompassing stack view.  Set the width and height on the images or the stack views?

Comment: Did you set constraints for top most stack view?

Comment: you do not need to set height and width you just need to give equal width and height to show [no parameter required for width and height and don't even give as we need for all sizes so no such parameters required]. should I show u some referance ? screenshots

Comment: Yes, I set constraints on the Top Stack View (with the cat and director image).  I also set a height on it.  Nothing different happened.  The Stack Views are set to "Distribution = Fill Equally".  Is that what you are referring to @iOSGeek?